# How to "Expand" a property using LinqPad and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linqpad

I have an entity set (lets call it Clients) that I am querying using LinqPad.

It is accessing the data via Entity Framework.  I am able to connect just fine and see most of my data.

However, Clients has a property called Location.  Location contains several properties by itself (State, City, Zip).

When I return all the Clients, the rows with no location show *null*.  But the rows that have a location just have an empty square.  (It is missing the box that has the data for the matching row of Location that is in the database.)

I know that my data is there and good.  (I am able to query it just fine using OData: `Clients.Expand("Location")`.

How can I do an "Expand" (or what ever is needed) to get to see the other associations/navigation properties in my result set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested it in LinQPad, but would try using [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx):  `Clients.Include("Location")`